# c# how to change font according to user input

Tags: c#, input, fonts

I have a box where the user can type out the font they want and a label with text below will change its font size accordingly. I'm not sure how to do this because most of the solutions I found online are not helpful. I tried to do it as shown below but my codes aren't working. Thank you for your help!

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newFont = textBox1.Text;
        label4.Font = new Font(label4.Font, label4.Font.Style ^ newFont);
        label4.Text = "Selected Font: " + newFont + ", Selected Font Size: 20";
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are using Windows Forms, but what exactly are you trying to achieve here? `label4.Font.Style ^ newFont` does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Its not clear what you want because you have only one textbox which take font name as user input and you want to change font size on font name ? How to change font size without taking font size input ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2 textboxes, one for font name and one for font size than you can change font and size of label as shown below

```
private void txtFontName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeFontTypeAndSize();

}

private void txtFontSize_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeFontTypeAndSize();
}

private void ChangeFontTypeAndSize()
{
    string fontName = txtFontName.Text;
    Font font = new Font(fontName, float.Parse((txtFontSize.Text == "" ? "11" : txtFontSize.Text)));
    label1.Font = font;
}
```

Comment: since the code is identical, the two event could be megered or better yet call a common function with a nice name..